# tag cloud search of text in linux

Tags: tags, file-search, pdftk, tagcloud

a lot of times i have to search through scientific papers that are on my computer. i think having a tagcloud would help. is there a program that creates a tagcloud picture in ubuntu?

ideally i would like to do the following

1. change my library of pdfs to text (pdftk)
2. make a cloud of all the text (?)
3. click on a tag or run the tag cloud generator for the needed tag
4. repeat the process until i find the paper that i'm looking for.

to summarize, i'm looking for a command line tag generator tool for linux that can be integrated into the procedure that i outlined above

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? I hear 'tag generator' and keep thinking Tagxedo, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: i added a summery in the end that made the question more specific